# How to compare lines of a text file with a variable

Tags: php

I have a text file which logs user's IP addresses, and I'm trying to compare each existing address with a visitor's IP address to see if they match.

If they do not match, I want the user's IP address to be written to the text file - otherwise I don't want anything to be written to the text file.

At the moment, all IP addresses are being written to the text file even if they match. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$ipFile = 'ip.txt';
$openip = fopen($ipFile, 'r');
$exists = false;

while(!feof($openip))
{
    $existingip = fgets($openip);

    if($existingip == $ip) {
        echo "Your ip already exists <br>";
        $exists = true;
    }
}
fclose($openip);

if($exists == false) {
    $openip = fopen($ipFile, 'a');
    fwrite($openip, $ip . "\r\n");
    echo "Your IP has been logged <br>";
    fclose($openip);
}
else {
    echo "Your IP is already stored <br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Why not use a database? an `INSERT IGNORE` would be much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make your code more raedable:

```
$file = file($ipFile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
if (in_array($ip, $file))  
        echo "Your ip already exists <br>";
else {
    $openip = fopen($ipFile, 'a');
    fwrite($openip, $ip . "\r\n");
    echo "Your IP has been logged <br>";
    fclose($openip);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to read the file into an array:

```
$arrayIpFile = file($ipFile);

if(in_array($ip, $arrayIpFile)){
  //Exist
}else{
 // not exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$ipFile = 'ip.txt';
If(preg_match_all("/".preg_quote($ip)."/", file_get_contents($ipFile)){
      Echo "Your IP is already stored <br>";
}else{
      //append file as you do now
}
```